# How to assign default value for dynamic pick list in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, picklist, dynamic-visualforce

i want to display all standard and custom objects in my organisation using visualforce dynamic pick list and i want to assign default value "Contact" at initial loading of page how to achieve these requirement.

**Note**: i am not using standard field to display my pick list values

I tried below code but it is showing all meta data and also not displaying default value.

**Page:**

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1" style="width: 21%;">    
    <apex:selectoptions value="{!ObjectNames}"/>    
</apex:selectList>
```

**Controller:**

```
public String selectedObject {get; set;}
public List<SelectOption> getObjectNames() 
{
    List<SelectOption> objNames = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<String> entities = new List<String>(schemaMap.keySet());
    entities.sort();
    for(String name : entities)
    {
        objNames.add(new SelectOption(name,name));
    }
    return objNames;
}
```

Comment: here my question is related to dynamic pick list not standard one and also need to display all objects in that dynamic pick list

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
public String selected
{
    get
    {
        return (selected == null) ? 'Contact' : selected;
    }
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code you can use to get the names of all objects in your organisation:

```
for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
    system.debug( 'Sobject Label Name: ' + objResult.getLabel() );   
}
```

Filter out objects that you want to put in the picklist.To make Contact default value, initialize 'Selected Value' as contact in the constructor

Comment: Hi Abhijeet,Thanks for your response.
above code retrieving all meta data values but i want only standard and custom object details.